# Need to read a string only from server

Tags: android, httpresponse

```
 DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse=defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);

                InputStream inputStream=httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

I am trying to communicate with a server with this code in AsyncTask.

The server is arduino(microcontroller) controlled server.
The server is working fine. I tried it with browser with the url.

The problem is that the I made the server to respond only with a string of "OK" as acknowledgement without a http header like below or any other thing to reduce the overload.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 128
Connection: close
```

When I run this code I get error that the response is not valid http response.

Is there is way to get the acknowledgement string of "OK" only.

Comment: "When I run this code I get error that the response is not valid http response" -- that's because your server is not sending back a valid response. Your response claims that it is sending back 8000 bytes of HTML, and (apparently) it is not. Try sending back a valid response.

Comment: `without a http header like below or any other thing to reduce the overload` And this is your problem. Reduced overload at the price of not getting a valid HTTP response.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein . yeah I know it is not a valid http response. Is there is a way to program to get the string only?

Comment: I guess you already figured it out yourself.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein . Is there a way in programming to get the acknowledgement OK alone?

Comment: `while (true){Re-read my previous comment}`

Comment: @Frank N. Stein  I tried this kind of response with browser and an app called TCP client from Google play, I got the response OK which was displayed by them. Why can't I implement it?

Comment: Wrong. "OK" is what is displayed **to you**. Not what the device received, which is the `full HTTP response`.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein . when I reconfigure the server with other string values.  I get the same strings displayed to me at browsers end. I want the same way, to display the response in my app. Am I going wrong?

Comment: Probably, the browsers are "fault-tolerant" and can handle broken HTTP responses.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein yeah. Exactly. Can I implement the "fault-tolerant" way in my app? As the app TCP client I said before got it implemented and I got correct response and the app was also not too complicated. I don't know what code should I use to get it into my app.

Comment: I really have no idea. But I think the problem is `HttpResponse httpResponse=defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);` If I were you, I wouldn't go for a complicate solution and just respond with a valid HTTP response.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein. You know the microcontroller server is weak at communication. It takes more time if the response is bigger. You know I am thinking if a browser and some app could do it why can't we do it? But I just don't know how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really really don't want the overhead of http, then you can simply open your own socket, write your request, and read the response.  To me it sounds like more work than just adding a few headers in your response from arduino.

The java tutorial shows how to read/write with a socket. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: Could you give a sample code or link to do this? @digitaljoel